# Matlab: How to write column number into new column if logical condition is met

Tags: matlab, multiple-columns, logical-operators

I have a sample matrix like this in matlab (though my real matrix contains many more columns)

```
List = [0,0,1;1,0,0;0,1,0;0,1,0;0,0,0]

List =

     0     0     1
     1     0     0
     0     1     0
     0     1     0
     0     0     0
```

What I am trying to find is a way how I could summarize the conditions which are TRUE (=1) into a new variable with just one column, but that indicates the column number in a structure such as the following list

```
ListNew =

     3
     1
     2
     2
     0
```

Is there a function or an easy way to do this in matlab?

Comment: So, can you have multiple ones in a row? If so, what would be the output like?

Comment: no, it can only contain one true condition or none. if 1 is specified, the column name should be written out, if the whole row contains 0 a zero should be placed in the new column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a simpler way with `find()`

```
[ListNew,~] = find(List');
```

Taking into account the comment below it can be modified as follows:

```
ListNew=zeros(5,1);
[Col,Row] = find(List');
ListNew(Rows)=Col;
```

Comment: this is a great solution, thank you. however i also have some rows which don't contain any true conditions (all zeros) such as in this matrix `List = [0,0,1;1,0,0;0,1,0;0,1,0;0,0,0]` (sorry I didn't mention this in my OP, but edited it). If I use your code to this new matrix, the 0 row gets lost.

Answer (score 3):

If your matrix is only `0`s and `1`s and you have just one `1` in each row then you can do this,

```
List = List .* repmat(1:size(List,2),size(List,1),1);
sum(List,2)
ans =
     3
     1
     2
     2
     3
```

Answer (score 1):

One-liner solution with `sum`, `cumsum` & `fliplr` -

```
out = sum(cumsum(fliplr(List),2),2)
```

Another approach with `max` for a two-lines solution -

```
[idx,valid] = max(List,[],2)
out = idx.*valid
```